# Failed to find provider info for com.teslacoilsw.notifier

Tags: android

I download Plus-Messenger code from github. But when run, It crashes for this error:

```
 Failed to find provider info for com.teslacoilsw.notifier
```

How can i solve this error?

Comment: nobody have any solution?

Answer (score 3):

The "provider" for "com.teslacoilsw.notifier" is an app that exposes `content://com.teslacoilsw.notifier` URLs. This app is the paid version of the Nova launcher *Nova Launcher Prime* plus the plugin *TeslaUnread for Nova Launcher*.

So you are likely using the free version of Nova or an entirely different launcher.

One way or another: Plus-Messenger must not crash when `content://com.teslacoilsw.notifier/unread_count` is not available. If it does, this is a bug in Plus-Messenger.

---

If you do not get the error message anymore but still do not receive the badges, ensure Plus-Messenger is activated in the "Common" section in the TeslaUnread settings.